# I want to sum of count field in mongo by aggregation, and array is dynamic, format is spend_imp->today_date(everyday new array gen,)->count.......)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
    array = "spend_imp" : {
              "2019-11-19" : {
                  "created" : 1574167415264.0,
                  "count" : 1
              },
              "2019-11-20" : {
                  "count" : 4,
                  "created" : 1574229189457.0
              }
          }
    try {
        Main_add_list.aggregate( [
            { $match: {"add_id" : data.add_id }  },
            {$project:{
                "_id":1,
                "spend_imp":1,
                "Total_spend":{$sum:"$spend_imp.2019-11-19"},
            }},
            ] ).then((result) => {
                    return callback(result);        
                }).catch((err) =>{
                    console.log(err);
                    return callback(err);
                })
    }
    catch(e){ return callback(null); }
```

I make array dynamically.

Array format is `spend_imp` -> today_date (everyday new nested array under `spend_imp` gen.) -> `count` field in today_date (e.g., 11/20/2019). So I want to sum all `count`. e.g., I have 2 array `11/19/2019` and `11/20/2019`, so I want sum of both arrays count.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: first-> i create array under spend_imp...as i mention above
second-> i created dynamic array succesfully...and after this i want to sum of count field

Comment: "spend_imp1" : {
        "2019-11-20" : {
            "count" : 1,
            "created" : 1574235614677.0
        },
        "2019-11-19" : {
            "count" : 1,
            "created" : 1574235614677.0
        }
    }
this is my array as you see there r 2 array ..and array gen. daily ..now i want $sum of all count under all sub_array

Comment: okay, but in which field do you want to  group by ?

Comment: I want total sum of count field